# Index exceeds matrix dimensions when trying to access position vectors

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, matlab-cvst

I am simply reading an image and wish to visualize the bounding boxes returned by blob analysis of matlab which returns position vectors.
Here is my code

```
img = imread(file_name);
img = im2bw(img);

 gblob = vision.BlobAnalysis('AreaOutputPort', true, ... % Set blob analysis handling
                'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
                'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true', ...
                'MinimumBlobArea', 0, ...
                'MaximumBlobArea', 600000, ...
                'MaximumCount', 1000, ...
                'MajorAxisLengthOutputPort',true, ...
                'MinorAxisLengthOutputPort',true, ...
                'OrientationOutputPort',true);


            [Area,centroid, bbox, MajorAxis, MinorAxis,Orientation] = step(gblob, img);
            % each bbox is position vector of the form [x y width height]
             for i = 1:1:length(MajorAxis)
                 figure;imshow(img(bbox(i,2):bbox(i,2) + bbox(i,4),bbox(i,1):bbox(i,1)+bbox(i,3)));
             end
```

On doing so i get an error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` I have also tried

```
figure;imshow(img(bbox(i,1):bbox(i,1) + bbox(i,3),bbox(i,2):bbox(i,2)+bbox(i,4)));
```

but i still end up getting the same error.

here is a sample image where this code gives an error

[image: https://www.aagga.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Sample.jpg]

Comment: It means the index, `i`, is larger than the number of rows (matrix dimension) in `bbox`.

Comment: i believe the problem is with dimesions for `img` and not `bbox`, i have tried printing `bbox` seperately, that works fine

Comment: Ok, great, then it means that the index, `bbox(i,1):bbox(i,1) + bbox(i,3),bbox(i,2):bbox(i,2)+bbox(i,4)`, is larger than the matrix dimensions of `img`.

Comment: i got that. i am just wondering how is that possible, Since the left x corner coordinate + width and left corner y coordinate + height should not exceed image dimension.

Comment: Since you have not provided a [mcve], then only you can figure out the answer to that.

Comment: I have added a sample image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple case of mis-indexing.  The blob detector returns the `x` and `y` coordinates of the top left corner of the blob.  `x` in this case are the **horizontal** coordinates while `y` is the **vertical**.  Therefore, you simply need to swap how you're accessing the image as the vertical needs to come first, then horizontal after.

Also with regards to your image, I would **invert** the image because the object would be considered as a dark object on white background once you convert it to binary.  The blob detector works by detecting white objects on black background.  Therefore, invert the image and do some morphological closing to clean up the noise once that happens:

```
img = imread('http://www.aagga.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Sample.jpg');
img = ~im2bw(img); %// Change - invert
img_clean = imclose(img, strel('square', 7)); %// Change, clean the image
```

I get this image now:

```
imshow(img_clean);
```

[image]

Not bad.... now run your actual blob detector.  Take note that the image you put inside the blob detector is the run variable name. You'll need to call it `img_clean` now:

```
gblob = vision.BlobAnalysis('AreaOutputPort', true, ... 
            'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
            'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true', ...
            'MinimumBlobArea', 0, ...
            'MaximumBlobArea', 600000, ...
            'MaximumCount', 1000, ...
            'MajorAxisLengthOutputPort',true, ...
            'MinorAxisLengthOutputPort',true, ...
            'OrientationOutputPort',true);


[Area,centroid, bbox, MajorAxis, MinorAxis,Orientation] = step(gblob, img_clean);
```

Now finally extract out each blob:

```
% each bbox is position vector of the form [x y width height]
for i = 1:1:length(MajorAxis)
    figure;
    imshow(img_clean(bbox(i,2):bbox(i,2) + bbox(i,4),bbox(i,1):bbox(i,1)+bbox(i,3))); %// Change
end
```

I now get the following 9 figures:

[image]

Take note that the above isn't perfect because the perimeter of the sign is disconnected so the blob detector will interpret this as different blobs.  One way you could combat this is to vary the threshold of the image, or perhaps use [`graythresh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) to perform adaptive thresholding so you can ensure that the border is connected properly.  However, this is a good way to start tackling your problem.

## Minor Note

A much easier way to do this is to do away with the Computer Vision Toolbox and use the Image Processing Toolbox.  Specifically use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) and use the `Image` property to extract out the actual images that the blobs contain themselves:

```
%// Code from before
img = imread('http://www.aagga.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Sample.jpg');
img = ~im2bw(img); %// Change - invert
img_clean = imclose(img, strel('square', 7)); %// Change, clean the image

%// Create regionprops structure with desired properties
out = regionprops(img_clean, 'BoundingBox', 'Image');

%// Cycle through each blob and show the image
for ii = 1 : numel(out)
    figure;
    imshow(out(ii).Image);
end
```

This should achieve the same thing as I showed you above.  You can look at the documentation for more details on what kinds of properties `regionprops` returns for you per blob.

Comment: the part `img(bbox(i,2):bbox(i,2) + bbox(i,4),bbox(i,1):bbox(i,1)+bbox(i,3))` is still the same as my code. i guess the problem is that the bounding boxes output from the function sometimes are actually beyond the image. correct me if i am wrong. Thank you for your answer

Comment: That actually may be it. I didn't see that you used the right order of coordinates in your code. I only saw the last part you had as a separate line in the end. OK well make sure you invert the image before performing the detection. I suspect you may be right in your analysis due to the inversion of the objects in intensity.